# Weapon Class Organization

Tags: java, 2d, architecture, lwjgl

Im making a game and i want to organise my weapons, and im having a few doubts on not only the best architecture but also on how to use it properly:

The First approach is to make a single Weapon class with a Type variable, and create every weapon, melee or ranged, in there. That way, even handeling collision would be "easy" (i have a collisionManager class where i handle all the collision (with pointers to collideable game elements), but thats also a problem, since weapons might have different ways to collide, lets say if im using a projectile weapon, like a pistol, i only need to check collision with its bullets, while a knife's is all about its range, so the Type variable would be very useful for that). The downside, i believe, is that:

1 - In the future, the class might get very big and maybe complex (i intend to add lasers, flamethrowers and rocket launchers so...)

2 - Every mob that posesses a "Weapon" object initialized would have data to use every weapon, when some enemies might just use one of them (lets say i have an enemy that just melee hits, which i might say its the knife), and althought i might be overreacting about the memory it wastes, it bothers me.

The second approach is the classic, yet quite attractive, hierarchical one, where i would create a class Weapon similar to this:

```
public abstract class zWeapon {

//weapon attack info
protected boolean attacking = false;
protected int damage;
protected long startTime;
protected long delay;
protected long elapsed;

public void attack(double X, double Y, double angleShoot)
{
    if(attacking) return;

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    attacking = true;

    useWeapon();
}

protected abstract void useWeapon();

public void update()
{
    if(attacking)
    {
        elapsed = (System.nanoTime()-startTime) / 1000000;
        if(elapsed >= delay)
            attacking = false;
    }
}

protected abstract void draw();}
```

(forget about the "z" behind Weapon)

and then create extensions like MeleeWeapon, ProjectileWeapon, Laser etc

What confuses me, is how to properly use this. My only idea to use this. if a mob has a Weapon, and a certain mob only uses Knife, it makes sense that i say weapon = new Knife(); and the mob uses the knife as it should. But lets say, for example, the player. The Player can use every weapon, eventually. And i would probabily create an array of weapons with every weapon object initialized, and id change the weapon variable everytime i had to change weapon. The problems that come up to my mind are the following:

1 - If i use it like this, if i change weapon variable from, lets say, pistol to knife, the vector of bullets in pistol would stop being updated since im now updating a different weapon.

2 - The collision would be a harder work, i dont want to use instanceof to check which type of collision i should do with the weapon against my game elements...

So as you see i have alot of confusion going on in this Weapon Class architecture, would you ease my mind with a few solutions/hints/tips?

Comment: Don't abuse inheritance.  Look into component models.  http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/  Use events for collision handling.  And I don't know what you mean by "vector of bullets," but I'm scare anyway - bullets should not be owned by the gun, but rather distinct game objects that simply reference the player/weapon that fired them for stats tracking.

Comment: I mean vector just as it is, its a list of bullets since i have to store them somewhere, and i like java's Vector for that, its easy to use, i could use Arraylist but meh, at this particular moment, the difference isnt that aggressive. Your approach of the bullets having a pointer to the gun is quite interesting actually. The Weapon having an array of bullets makes sense in an OO architecture, since it makes sense in real life, but it might indeed be not as efficient as that approach. And ill definitively read the component models now. Thanks for your time and help : ) Idk how to event though.

Comment: Something that bothers me is how people are so in disagreement about hierarchy, in the way that some say its better to have just one class with the various types to avoid the abuse of inheritance but others say inheritance is better because it avoids a class being overwhelmed with variables from all the different wished types : /

Comment: No, it does not make sense in OO architecture, and your understanding (and most novice programmers' understanding) of OO is simply flawed.  The problem arises when you try to _model taxonomy_ in OO ("real life").  Yeah, a Laser _is-a_ Weapon, but the code doesn't care.  The code cares that Laser _has-a_ Weapon interface.  Your designers also want easy composition.  Don't abuse inheritance; use it when you need to _extend interfaces_ ("interface" in the Computer Science meaning, not necessarily the Java language meaning) and avoid it when you are just trying to group related things.

Comment: I see, I've got a lot to learn, I wish I knew someone like you to teach me. Thanks for your help, I'll try to de-flaw my knowledge.

Comment: As a simple example of how inheritance fails horribly in this case, what happens when one of your designers wants to add a laser-shooting axe?  You can't be both a MeleeWeapon and a LaserWeapon at the same time with inheritance, especially single-inheritance.  You could have a MeleeWeapon component and a RangedWeapon component both mixed into the same composition.  Statically via _aggregation_ (or even interface inheritance in Java), or dynamically with a component model.

Comment: You can always use chat or gamedev.net if you're looking for extended discussions with experienced game developers to help hone your skills.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will definitely do so :) But just out of curiosity, what you think about using inheritance for the distinguishment between Game Elements, like:
-Game Element -> Moveable Game Element -> Mob|Bullet -> Player/Enemy etc? (not the best example but you got the point)

Comment: These kinds of discussions are better for the chatroom or e-mail, not comments.

Comment: @user2295607 regarding the "disagreement": Those are programming tools, there is a lot of them, all having it's pros and cons. There is no single super programming paradigm, that comes without any costs and only pros. People tend to like the tools they use, because they are familiar with it. It's good to leave the comfort zone once in a while, trying different approaches. At the end the day, pick the one that leads to your goal, and listen to advice from people that [got both kinds: country and western](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5B9PBq615Ac). Avoid fundamentalistic one sided views.

Comment: Yessir, thank you all for sharing your wisedom : )